# Create a batch file that plays an mp3 constantly

Tags: batch-file

I would like help creating a batch file that plays an mp3 infinitely. The only possible way it would be able to stop is through another batch file which I do not know how to do. Anyway, here is the code I already have.

```
@echo off
set "file=s.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
exit /b
```

edit: I don't want it to be stopped when the computer is shut down. So I would like the file to run on startup.

Comment: need more information.. does what you have work? if not, what is wrong/what error occurs etc.. and is this supposed to be a windows batch file?

Comment: @ShoeLace It works but when I close my laptop lid it quits.

Comment: the program quits? or it stops playing.. if it just stops playing then its just your laptop sleeping and stopping the audio.. if the program 'dies' then your batch will stop also as there is no looping on that..  hopefullly if you can state you issue clearer someone will eb able to help.

Comment: i will also mention there and probably numerous mp3 player apps that will play a file on loop..  aka window media player, or itunes.

Comment: @ShoeLace The batch file doesn't quit, audio just stops.